# C++ strongly typed enums in visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-c++

When I use a strongly typed enum in VS2010, for example:

```
enum eTest : long long
{
_test1                  = 0x0000000000000001,
_test2                  = 0x0000000000000002,
};
```

I get this warning:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173702.aspx

nonstandard extension used: specifying underlying type for enum 'enum'

Why is this? I thought VS2010 supported C++11? Also is a 64bit based enum safe between 64-32bit VS2010 compilers?

Edit:

Regarding the second part of my question: I asked about the 32 vs 64bit because OR'ing bit flags from a 64bit enum when targeting 32bit resulted in compiler errors. However I found out that the reason for is is because enabling Microsoft's Code Analysis causes this to break.

Comment: How could VS2010 possibly support the final version of C++11?  (Queue [Raymond Chen jokes about the Microsoft time machine](http://www.google.com/search?q=site:blogs.msdn.com%2Fb%2Foldnewthing%2F+time+machine).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++11 enums are done like this:

```
enum class eTest : long long
{
    _test1                  = 0x0000000000000001,
    _test2                  = 0x0000000000000002,
};
```

See [Strongly Type Enumerations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#Strongly_typed_enumerations)

[**EDIT**:] And I believe VS 2010 does not have the compiler that supports this.  I think C++11 enums were only [partially supported in the MSVC++ 10 Compiler](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx)

As far as sizes: check out [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3f49ktz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) that talks about sizes of data types.  Microsoft doesn't vary much between the 32 and 64 bit versions of their compiler.

Comment: IMHO, 7.2/5 doesn't limit enum bases to scoped enums.

Comment: @DyP At least wikipedia says that C++03 enums (the ones without the class moniker): "underlying integral type is implementation-defined".  Although looking at the spec it says that you can declare the underlying integral type for an normal enum.

Comment: Or alternatively, Visual C++ `enum class` is only partially supported by the C++11 Standard (since Visual C++ had it first by about five years).

Comment: @Bob Fincheimer: Yes, that's C++03 7.2/5. I'm talking about C++11 7.2/5.

Comment: @DyP I see in C++11 the underlying can be defined for a normal enum, thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

VS 2010 is not a full C++11 implementation: [Support For C++11/14/17 Features (Modern C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/hh567368(v=vs.140)#stl)

From Microsoft VS2010 documentation: [C++ Enumeration Declarations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/2dzy4k6e%28v%3Dvs.100%29)

The definition of a enum:

```
enum [tag] [: type] {enum-list} [declarator];
```

> **type** is the underlying type of the identifiers. This can be any scalar type, such as signed or unsigned versions of int, short, or long. bool or char is also allowed.

It doesn't say anything about `long long` (maybe documentation wasn't updated).